# Как сгенерировать ключ с помощью randint которого нет в списке

Tags: python, list

У меня есть переменная в которой хранится список с ключами строкового типа `412`, `413`.
`keys_now = ['412', '413']`
Мне необходимо сгенерировать новый ключ в диапазоне от `411` до `415`, то есть, чтобы новый ключ не был в списке `keys_now`.

У меня как-то ранее получилось это сделать, но я уже не помню, как правильно всё написать.

Сейчас у меня есть функция `generateKeyForNewCategory(categories)`, которая неправильно работает.

```
def generateKeyForNewCategory(categories):
    categories_Keys = getCategoriesKeys(categories)

    for _ in categories_Keys:
        random_category_key = str(randint(411, 415))
        if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:
            new_category_key = random_category_key

    print(new_category_key)
```

Comment: Вы просите, чтоб генерировалось в диапазоне от 411 до 412, а в коде `str(randint(411, 415))`..

Comment: Ошибся, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предложу ещё один вариант (без функции `getCategoriesKeys` и с циклом `while`) :

```
from random import randint

lst = ['412', '413']

def generateKeyForNewCategory(categories):
        while True:
            random_category_key = str(randint(411, 415))
            if random_category_key not in categories:
                new_category_key = random_category_key
                categories.append(new_category_key)
                break
        return new_category_key # также можно вывести список с добавленным значением

print(generateKeyForNewCategory(lst))
```

Кстати, можно и рекурсией обойтись:

```
from random import randint

lst = ['412', '413']

def generateKeyForNewCategory(categories):
        
        random_category_key = str(randint(411, 415))
        if random_category_key not in categories:
            
            new_category_key = random_category_key
            categories.append(new_category_key)
            
            return new_category_key
        else:
           return generateKeyForNewCategory(categories)
           

print(generateKeyForNewCategory(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

*Это можно сделать так:*

```
async def generateKeyForNewCategory():
    categories_Keys = [] # тут существующие ключи

    for _ in categories_Keys:
        random_category_key = str(randint(411, 415))
        if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:
            new_category_key = random_category_key
            return new_category_key
```