# Не работает код для генерации новых значений, которых нет в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Ранее я задавал вопрос - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327448/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-randint-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5), мне нужно было сгенерировать значение которого нет в списке, спустя немного времени я разобрался и получал абсолютно новый ключ без всяких ошибок с помощью этого кода:

```
def generateKeyForNewCategory():
    categories_Keys = ['41', '42'] # тут существующие ключи

    for _ in categories_Keys:
        random_category_key = str(randint(41, 43))
        if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:
            new_category_key = random_category_key
            return new_category_key
```

Сегодня я попытался использовать ещё раз свой код, только уже в другом файле, спустя несколько генераций, я получаю заместо ключа `None`, я не могу понять в чем проблема или ошибка, так как это абсолютно идентичный код, который я использовал в прошлый раз.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ты вставь после каждой строчки print с выводом чего-нибудь, чтобы было понятно, в какой именно строчке сейчас код, и посмотри, что происходит. Отладка кода - очень полезный навык. И в данном случае это не так и сложно. Подсказка: если в функции нет return, то она возвращает None.

Comment: Код довольно странный, конечно... Для чего там, например, цикл?

Comment: @Эникейщик цикл был добавлен, чтобы показать результаты после выполнения функции :)

Comment: Непонятно каким образом одно связано с другим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я получаю заместо ключа None

Это связано с тем, что вы в `if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:`  проверяете значение, удволетворяющее условию, но если это не так, то ничего не происходит.

Добавьте в конце функции условие для повторного вызова функции (сделайте рекурсию):

```
if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:
    ...
else:
    return generateKeyForNewCategory()
```

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такие вещи делают в "бесконечном цикле" пока не выполнится условие выхода:

```
def generateKeyForNewCategory():
    categories_Keys = ['41', '42'] # тут существующие ключи

    while True:
        random_category_key = str(randint(41, 43))
        if random_category_key not in categories_Keys:
            new_category_key = random_category_key
            return new_category_key
```

А у вас получается, что если два раза выпало значение из списка, то цикл заканчивается, и функция тоже заканчивается, ничего не вернув, а значит питон считает, что функция вернула `None`.